# Angular JS JSONP request on localhost

Tags: javascript, angularjs

my name is Catalin and I want to build an Angular app that renders data from a localhost node.js server. But I can't get it to communicate properly with the server, and the page remains empty. Here is my code:

Index page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>JS Bin</title>
     <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
     <script src="controller.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="MainController">

     <div>
      <h1>App</h1>
      <h1>{{people.age}}</h1>
     </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Controller:

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
     $http.jsonp('http://localhost:8080/person/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function(data){
     $scope.people = data;
    });
    }]);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can u show demo of not working

Comment: Check that http://localhost:8080/person/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK return something BTW you don't need JSONP if you are on localhost to localhost

Comment: JSONP requires that your server is returning the correct format. You should check to make sure that the response from your server looks something like `angular_callbacks_0({data})`. Note that it looks like a javascript function call, with the parenthesis and everything.